# Centering Hexagon

Tags: html, css

Hi i got this Hexagon css style from internet and i can't find to center the hexagons without jumping down or up...

I just need it to get centered but can't find it... I searched the internet and found another hexagon style but it didn't had any images in it so i couldn't use it...

This is what i got so far

https://jsfiddle.net/de3jzdd8/

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background:hsla(195,29%,97%,1.00);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display:block;

}
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#categories{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.clr:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
#categories li{
  position:relative;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:27.85714285714286%; /* = (100-2.5) / 3.5 */
  padding-bottom: 32.16760145166612%; /* =  width /0.866 */
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  visibility:hidden;
 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
#categories li:nth-child(3n+2){
  margin:0 1%;
}
#categories li:nth-child(6n+4){
  margin-left:0.5%;
}
#categories li:nth-child(6n+4), #categories li:nth-child(6n+5), #categories li:nth-child(6n+6) {
 margin-top: -6.9285714285%;
  margin-bottom: -6.9285714285%;
  
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
#categories li:nth-child(6n+4):last-child, #categories li:nth-child(6n+5):last-child, #categories li:nth-child(6n+6):last-child{
  margin-bottom:0%;
}
#categories li *{
  position:absolute;
  visibility:visible;
}
#categories li > div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  
 -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  
}

/* HEX CONTENT */
#categories li img{
  left:-100%; right:-100%;
  width: auto; height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;   
}

#categories div h1, #categories div p{
  width:90%;
  padding:0 5%;
  background-color:hsla(195,29%,97%,1.00); background-color: hsla(0,0%,42%,0.80);
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
}
#categories li h1{
  bottom:110%;
  font-style:italic;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:1.5em;
  padding-top:100%;
  padding-bottom:100%;
}
#categories li h1:after{
 content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1px; left:45%;
  width:10%;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1;
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
#categories li p{
 padding-top:50%;
 top:110%;
 padding-bottom:50%;
}


/* HOVER EFFECT  */

#categories li div:hover h1 {
  bottom:50%;
  padding-bottom:10%;
}

#categories li div:hover p{
  top:50%;
  padding-top:10%;
}
#fork{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:.5em .7em;
  margin:1%;
  transition: color .5s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#fork:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 130%; height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin:0 0 ;
  transform:translateX(-100%) skewX(-45deg);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
#fork:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#fork:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(0) skewX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul id="categories" class="clr">
  <li>
   <div>
        <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/6227418584_d5883b0948.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li><li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the `#categories` ul.

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background:hsla(195,29%,97%,1.00);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display:block;

}
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#categories{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: relative;
}
.clr:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
#categories li{
  position:relative;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:27.85714285714286%; /* = (100-2.5) / 3.5 */
  padding-bottom: 32.16760145166612%; /* =  width /0.866 */
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  visibility:hidden;
 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
#categories li:nth-child(3n+2){
  margin:0 1%;
}
#categories li:nth-child(6n+4){
  margin-left:0.5%;
}
#categories li:nth-child(6n+4), #categories li:nth-child(6n+5), #categories li:nth-child(6n+6) {
 margin-top: -6.9285714285%;
  margin-bottom: -6.9285714285%;
  
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
#categories li:nth-child(6n+4):last-child, #categories li:nth-child(6n+5):last-child, #categories li:nth-child(6n+6):last-child{
  margin-bottom:0%;
}
#categories li *{
  position:absolute;
  visibility:visible;
}
#categories li > div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  
 -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  
}

/* HEX CONTENT */
#categories li img{
  left:-100%; right:-100%;
  width: auto; height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;   
}

#categories div h1, #categories div p{
  width:90%;
  padding:0 5%;
  background-color:hsla(195,29%,97%,1.00); background-color: hsla(0,0%,42%,0.80);
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
}
#categories li h1{
  bottom:110%;
  font-style:italic;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:1.5em;
  padding-top:100%;
  padding-bottom:100%;
}
#categories li h1:after{
 content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1px; left:45%;
  width:10%;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1;
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
#categories li p{
 padding-top:50%;
 top:110%;
 padding-bottom:50%;
}


/* HOVER EFFECT  */

#categories li div:hover h1 {
  bottom:50%;
  padding-bottom:10%;
}

#categories li div:hover p{
  top:50%;
  padding-top:10%;
}
#fork{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:.5em .7em;
  margin:1%;
  transition: color .5s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#fork:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 130%; height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin:0 0 ;
  transform:translateX(-100%) skewX(-45deg);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
#fork:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#fork:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(0) skewX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul id="categories" class="clr">
  <li>
   <div>
        <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/6227418584_d5883b0948.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li><li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
```